# Understanding the "Paradox of Probability" : Infinite Sums of Zero Equal 1?

Tags: probability

Happy New Year everyone!

This is a concept I have never been able to understand that I call the "Paradox of Probability".

**Part 1: Discrete Case**

As a I understand, if $X$ is a discrete random variable, we discuss the idea of Probability in this case using the following concepts:

- **Sample Space (Ω)**: This is the set of all possible outcomes of a random experiment.
  $$\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \ldots, \omega_n\}$$
- **Events (E)**: An event is a subset of the sample space (e.g. specific outcome or a combination of outcomes of the experiment):
  $$E \subseteq \Omega$$
- **Probability Measure (P)**: A function that assigns a probability to each event. The probability of an event E is denoted by P(E). This function is Non-negative( For all E, P(E) ≥ 0 AND P($\Omega$) = 1)

  $$P: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow [0, 1]$$
  such that for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$, $P(E) \geq 0$ and $P(\Omega) = 1$.
- **Sigma Algebra (F)**: This is a collection/subset of all possible events (subsets of $\omega$):
  $$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega) = \{E | E \subseteq \Omega\}$$

As an example, consider a single (fair) 6 sided dice. For me at least, it is quite logical that:

- **Sample Space** : The set of all possible outcomes of rolling the die: $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$
- **Events (E)**: Any event in the sample space. As an example, the event "roll an even number": $E = \{2, 4, 6\}$
- **Probability Measure (P)**: A function that assigns a probability to each event. In this problem, each outcome is equally likely, so the probability of each outcome is 1/6. The probability measure P assigns to each event E a number P(E) in [0, 1] such that:
  $$P(\{1\}) = P(\{2\}) = P(\{3\}) = P(\{4\}) = P(\{5\}) = P(\{6\}) = \frac{1}{6}$$
  For example, the probability of the event $E=$"roll an even number" is:
  $$P(E) = P(\{2, 4, 6\}) = P(\{2\}) + P(\{4\}) + P(\{6\}) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$
- **Sigma Algebra (F)**: This is a collection of all possible events and subsets of $\Omega$  In this problem, the sigma algebra $F$ is the power set of $\Omega$.

**My Question:** I am having trouble extending these concepts to the continuous case for some continuous random variable $Y$ (i.e. the paradox). In short:

- **Continuous Sample Space (Ω)**: For a continuous random variable, the sample space Ω is an interval of real numbers (for example, over some range $a,b$:
  $$\Omega = [a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$
- **Infinite Events ($E_i$)**: In the continuous case, I think its logical to assume that there are an infinite number of events. For example, consider an infinite sequence of disjoint events $E_i$, where each event corresponds to a single point in the sample space (where $x_i$ is a point in the sample space $\Omega$):
  $$E_i = \{x_i\} \quad \text{for} \quad i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$
- **Probability of a Single Event ($E_i$)**:  Here is where the "paradox" starts. The probability of any single event $E_i$ is zero in the continuous case (this is by definition). If $f()$ is the probability density function of the random variable $Y$, then:
  $$P(E_i) = \int_{x_i}^{x_i} f(u) du = 0$$
- **Sum of Probabilities (Paradox)**: Perhaps I am understanding this incorrectly, but to me, the sum of the probabilities of all these individual events is the sum of an infinite number of zeros, which is still zero:
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(E_i) = P(E_1) + P(E_2) + P(E_3) + \ldots = 0 + 0 + 0 + \ldots = 0$$

In calculus, we learn about Reimann Sum - the summation of all infinitesimally small parts of a function over some range is equal to the integral of this function over this range. However, the total probability over the entire range of the random variable is equal to 1 (by definition):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) \, du = 1$$

This integral sums up the probabilities over all possible outcomes, and it equals 1 even though the probability of any individual outcome is zero (paradox).

**Can someone please help me explain how this sum can be both 0 and 1 at the same time?**

I feel I have likely oversimplified all of this, incorrectly understood the definitions of these concepts and their intended use cases, and overlooked some additional concepts in mathematics that are required to patch of all this together (e.g. concepts from Measure Theory, Real Analysis, etc.).

**Can someone please help me understand how this paradox is resolved?**

Thanks!

Comment: Probability is additive for countable sums, not for uncountable sums.

Comment: @lulu: thank you for your reply! this is exactly the type of insights that I am interested in learning about! thank you so much!

Comment: Same notion exists in [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) generally.

Comment: @lulu Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg the comment by OP that follows lulu's succint comment shows that this question should he closed rather than attracting formal answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could express the same thing just in terms of geometry, without mentioning probability: the interval $[0,1]$ has length $1$ while each point in $[0,1]$ has length $0$. Or the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ has area $1$ while each horizontal slice $[0,1] \times \{y\}$ with $0 \leq y \leq 1$ has area $0$. Do you consider either of  those to be  paradoxes?

A resolution of the paradox for you may be the distinction between countable and uncountable sets.  When $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ is a *countable* set of *disjoint* events, $P(\bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_n) = \sum_{n \geq 1} P(E_n)$, which is called countable additivity. However, *there is no uncountable additivity*, where you sum over an uncountable set.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! As per the first paragraph, no I don't see any paradoxes.

Comment: By countable additive, you mean like this? $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)$$ (source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-additive_set_function)

Comment: So in the a,b interval of the real line, this is considered an uncountable set? And since there is no countable additivity property in uncountable sets... the sum of an uncountable set where each element has 0 probability... this sum can still be non-zero? Am i correct? Can this be proven? Thanks!

Comment: Countable additivity is not just an equation, but an equation *with hypotheses*, in this case that the $A_n$'s are disjoint.  You wrote $\mu$ where I wrote $P$, but they mean the same thing.

Comment: There *is* countable additivity in uncountable sets: $[a,b]$ when $a < b$ is uncountable (that is a theorem, it's not merely "considered" uncountable, but really is), and when $A_n$ is a sequence of disjoint intervals in $[a,b]$, we have $\mu(\bigcup A_n) = \sum \mu(A_n)$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$.

Comment: You wrote "the sum of an uncountable set where each element has 0 probability... this sum can still be non-zero? Am i correct?" I'd say you're using phrases whose meaning you don't know. What is "the sum of an uncountable set"?  It might not be easy to locate a definition of that anywhere, because it is a largely useless concept: no matter how you define a sum of  an uncountable set of  nonnegative numbers, you'll find that only countably many of those numbers could possibly be nonzero, so this concept quickly reduces to a sum over a countable set.

Answer (score -2):

There are $2$ ways for $P(E) = 0$.

For $n$ = Number of outcomes that satisfy event $E$ and $N$ is the size of the *sample space* and $P(E) = \frac{n}{N}$

1. When $n = 0$ even when $N \ne \infty$
2. When $N = \infty$ even when $n \ne 0$. Of course, $n \ne \infty$

Comment: Sorry, but this is completely wrong

Comment: What's the correct answer then?

Comment: @AgentSmith if $N = \infty$ (uncountable) and $n$ is also an uncountable infinity $P(E) \not = 0$ which your answer implies.