# How Can Infinite Sums of Zero Sum to 1?

Tags: probability

Recently, I posted a question over here [Understanding the "Paradox of Probability" : Infinite Sums of Zero Equal 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837127/understanding-the-paradox-of-probability-infinite-sums-of-zero-equal-1) on the "paradox of probability" : i**f for a continuous random variable, the probability of the random variable taking a single value is 0 - wouldn't summing the probability of the random variable taking all possible values also result in 0?**

Here, I received the following answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4837141/791334):

> You could express the same thing just in terms of geometry, without
> mentioning probability: the interval $[0,1]$ has length $1$ while each
> point in $[0,1]$ has length $0$. Or the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$
> has area $1$ while each horizontal slice $[0,1] \times \{y\}$ with $0
> > \leq y \leq 1$ has area $0$. Do you consider either of  those to be
> paradoxes?
>
> A resolution of the paradox for you may be the distinction between
> countable and uncountable sets.  When $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ is a
> *countable* set of *disjoint* events, $P(\bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_n) = \sum_{n \geq 1} P(E_n)$, which is called countable additivity.
> However, *there is no uncountable additivity*, where you sum over an
> uncountable set.

This is the first time I have been introduced to these concepts and have spent the day trying to learn more about them.

The idea of Countable Additivity seems logical - if you have some finite shape, and divide this shape into small chunks, the sum of all chunks should be equal to the total area of the shape (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#/media/File:Countable_additivity_of_a_measure.svg):

$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$

I can see this for a dice question - the probability of each event is $1/6$, thus adding them all together results in $1$:

$$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{6} E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} P(E_i) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = 1$$

**My Question:** I am still struggling to understand "uncountable additivity" and how probabilities can sum to 1.

In the second paragraph of the answer, it's written that there is NO uncountable additivity over an uncountable set. I think I can illustrate this concept by the following idea:

For continuous random variable $X$ t on the interval $[0, 1]$. The sample space is $\Omega = [0, 1]$. For each real number $x$ in $[0, 1]$, define an event $E_x$ that corresponds to the outcome $X = x$. Each of these events is mutually exclusive, and the probability of each event is $0$ (since $X$ is a continuous random variable). If we try to sum up the probabilities of all these individual outcomes, we would be trying to perform an "uncountable sum of zeros":

$$\sum_{x \in [0, 1]} P(E_x) = \sum_{x \in [0, 1]} 0 = 0$$

$$P(\bigcup_{x \in [0, 1]} E_x) = \int_{0}^{1} P(E_x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} 0 \, dx = 0$$

From a non probability perspective, I can also see this in basic integrals:

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)\Delta x$$
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)\frac{b - a}{n}$$
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$$

In my math classes, I was never able to understand this and just moved on to pass the course. As $n$ becomes very large (i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty}$), then $\frac{b - a}{n}$ should be $0$. So again, infinite sums of $0$ appear to be equal to a non-zero result. It seems the only answer to this is a "faith based answer" that is slapped together to make it work - since we are dealing with an uncountable set, there is no uncountable additivity, therefore infinite sums of zero can (somehow) sum to a non-zero result. To me, this sounds like the comedian Mitch Hedberg's joke : "*An escalator is never really out of service, it just becomes a staircase. Sorry for the convenience!*"

Can someone please help me understand how "infinite sums of zero can still sum to 1"?

Thanks!

**References:**

- [https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/paradox/chapters/measure/measure.html](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/teaching/paradox/chapters/measure/measure.html)

Comment: Can you understand $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\times\frac1x=1$?

Answer (score 4):

> So again, infinite sums of 0
> appear to be equal to a non-zero result.

Not quite. Your focus was on $\frac{b-a}{n}$, but $n$ appears **two** times in that expression: the second time is in the upper bound of the summation:
$$
\frac{b-a}{\color{blue}{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\color{blue}{n}} f(x_i)
$$
So while the factor out front shrinks, you're summing up even more values of the function. For well-behaved functions, these two phenomena "destructively interfere" in a sense, usually reaching a finite value and often nonzero. For others, it can blow up altogether. (To see why, note that the integral can often be thought of as the area under a curve.)

In general, the logical flaw here is the claim
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \right)\left( \lim_{n \to \infty}  b_n \right)
$$
but this is not always the case, with problems arising for nonconvergent limits (e.g. those that go to $\pm \infty$). Here we have
$$
a_n = \frac{b-a}{n} \qquad b_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
$$
We can see why the claim may not hold for each basic examples:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot \frac 1 n = 1
\ne \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} n  \right) \left( \lim_{n \to \infty}   \frac 1 n \right)
$$
where the expression on the right-hand side is ill-defined (a $\infty \times 0$ type).

---

I'm not sure I can personally do more to help you. However, I do think it might be worth noting that the study of measures would be a tad pointless if uncountable additivity held. Take any set $S$ in whichever space you like; then
$$
\mu(S) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{x \in S} \{x\} \right)
$$
If the measure of a point is zero, e.g. with the Lebesgue measure, then every set in that space has measure zero (and is measurable to begin with), obviously problematic.

Perhaps one way to think about it is in terms of what you're adding up. Your idea seems to be in the vein of adding up points to make conclusions about measure (areas, volumes, etc.). But a point is zero-dimensional.

Think of an already-stated example: the square, decomposed into lines. You can easily say that each line has a length, but no area. Why should adding these up give you something that has an area? Why should adding up a bunch of numbers of the type
$$
3 \text{ in.}+
4 \text{ in.}+
5 \text{ in.}+\cdots
$$
give you an answer that has units in terms of area, $\text{in.}^2$?

---

I don't like that resolution personally, so perhaps another one, a tad more technical - it's a matter of framing.

When thinking of probabilities, even discrete ones, everything should be framed in terms of area. In the discrete case, your early-level basic problems can be formulated in terms of the counting measure as a result (or in terms of step functions if you prefer).

Let's think of a basic example. Consider a random experiment, say rolling two dice and recording their sum. (Both are fair and six-sided.) Record their results in a histogram:

[image]

If we add some edges and a first bar, it becomes easier to think of this as the graph of a  function:

[image]

Namely, we may think of it as the function
$$
f(x) = \operatorname{Prob}\Big( \text{dice sum} = \lfloor x \rfloor \Big)
$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the "floor" of $x$, or its integer part - what you get when you round down. This function has a name: the **probability distribution function** or **pdf** (for the random variable that is the sum of these dice).

Results where you would naively add or otherwise manipulate these numbers - "what is the probability the sum of the dice is between $3$ and $6$?" for instance - can be phrased in terms of the area of these bars, in terms of the area under $f$. Or, that is, in terms of an integral - and in either sense, we need to appeal to measures to do that.

So in reality you were playing with measure theory all along, just not from the ground up. So perhaps you can think of the study of continuous sets as having seen that the rules - like measures - for discrete sets no longer cleanly hold, and we need to change our framing or the rules altogether, and have found instead rules that hold adequately for the discrete case too, just reframed.

---

There are a couple of 3Blue1Brown videos I think that might also be more useful viewing:

- [His video introducing integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfG8ce4nNh0&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=8), from his "essence of calculus" series
- [An application of this to a probability problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA4JkHKZM50), in particular introducing pdfs in the continuous case

Comment: thank you so much for your wonderful answer! I see on your profile that you play pokemonshowdown ... so do I sometimes! ;)

Answer (score 3):

> If we try to sum up the probabilities of all these individual outcomes, we would be trying to perform an "uncountable sum of zeros":

We cannot sum an uncountably infinite set. When we do probability over continuous spaces, we use integrals. Do not think of $E_x$ as an event, but rather just as a real number, since any uncountably infinite set of events has a correspondence with the real numbers. Another slight error here:

$$P\left( \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]}E_x \right) = \int_0^1 P(E_x) dx$$
This is confusing notation because how is this supposed to be evaluated? We can't take the integral of a probability function, and you can't evaluate it within the  integral since it's with respect to $x$. When you do probability over continuous spaces, you should have some sort of function that explains this, like a pdf. There could be other examples, I'm not sure off of the top of my head but you cannot take the integral of the probability function is the main point.

> In my math classes, I was never able to understand this and just moved on to pass the course. As $n$
> becomes very large (i.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$
> ), then $\frac{b−a}{n}$
> should be $0$
> .

Heuristically, it is not actually infinity, or actually $0$, for continuous or uncountably infinite spaces. That is the big concept here. $0$ is a placeholder for some very small value. When we sum up all these values, we aren't adding $0 + 0  + 0 + \ldots$, we are adding an infinitesimal value. It is still something, just not something we can represent.

You say this is a "faith based answer", I think this should be called a notation based answer. Our convenience assumes that everyone understands this idea perfectly, but clearly this isn't true. You may never get an answer you deem acceptable and perfect, I would recommend reteaching yourself some of calculus $1$, possibly $2$, and an introduction to mathematical analysis and or probability textbook. When you want to relearn math rigorously, it is best to start from the basics to make sure you don't miss anything or aren't operating on bad habits.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I think this is one of the best answers I have ever received!

Comment: "Do not think of $E_x$ as an event, but rather just as a real number" . But can't I call this "real number" as an "Event"?

Comment: You can but I think in terms of thinking about it this way may help, but if it doesn’t then don’t! Think about it however works best for you (so long as it doesn’t cause problems) until you are able to have a rigorous understanding of everything that is at work here, which would go towards understanding measure theory.